# Reusing a form in multiple views

Tags: php, html, laravel, api, reusability

I am starting a new project and I have a few decisions to make in regards to user submitted forms. I will be using the PHP Laravel framework for this project. Here is a quick rundown of where forms can be submitted from:

- Frontend (consumer facing) portion of the website
- The customer's "My Account" portal
- Our internal custom CRM that customer service reps can use to take orders

There are approximately 20 different services that we offer. And I would like for all of our services to be available for purchase from the 3 different locations listed above. Also, a quick note, all 3 locations have different UIs. Here is what I would like to achieve if possible:

- I do not want to manually/hard code the HTML form inputs for all 20 services for the 3 locations above
- It would be ideal if I could call an internal API (or some other method) which would provide me the form structure/steps/inputs and I could parse that and build the form according to the UI of where it will be placed

This is a theory I have always wanted to attempt but I am just not sure if this is the way professionals would do it.

Comment: The API approach is the right idea, imo. Maintain data in one place, build UIs around the responses. Look at specs like JSON Schema and JSON API. I use the latter extensively across projects.

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to what you mean here. I don't know how different each service is, but you could just contain all of your services in one model and just create reusable form partials.